# Quizlet API not available

Tags: api-key

I’m not sure if this is the right place to ask this but I’m trying to use the Quizlet API for a personal project I have but I can’t seem to find where to access the Quizlet API. It seems like there are a few pages on Quizlet about their API but all of them are now gone giving “The page you’re looking for is no longer available error”.

I’m just wondering if anyone knows how I could get the API key (I am relatively new to working with API’S).

Answer (score 22, accepted):

They are no longer supporting the API.
The answer from the support:

> Thanks for your interest in the Quizlet API. We are no longer supporting the Quizlet API, for commercial or personal use, and are not currently issuing any new API keys to potential developers.If you would like to be contacted about any future updates, please let us know by filling out this form: https://docs.google.com/forms/d/e/1FAIpQLScxmhsrGJGbnf0Y0qh9FiquWyDLiWZozc2aKcqczFL2SvYMvw/viewform

Comment: Thanks for posting, I can't help but feeling this is a missed opportunity. A question with >2k views..

Answer (score 3):

Seems that API is hosted at a different URL and may be working at this time. Here's a snippet that came up on google search and seems to be active.

https://www.thiscodeworks.com/get-quizlet-flashcards-via-api/61bbc4382e046e00150bd05b

```html
async function quizlet(id){
    let res = await fetch(`https://quizlet.com/webapi/3.4/studiable-item-documents?filters%5BstudiableContainerId%5D=${id}&filters%5BstudiableContainerType%5D=1&perPage=5&page=1`).then(res => res.json())
    let currentLength = 5;
    let token = res.responses[0].paging.token
    let terms = res.responses[0].models.studiableItem;
    let page = 2;
    console.log({token, terms})
    while (currentLength >= 5){
        let res = await fetch(`https://quizlet.com/webapi/3.4/studiable-item-documents?filters%5BstudiableContainerId%5D=${id}&filters%5BstudiableContainerType%5D=1&perPage=5&page=${page++}&pagingToken=${token}`).then(res => res.json());
        terms.push(...res.responses[0].models.studiableItem);
        currentLength = res.responses[0].models.studiableItem.length;
        token = res.responses[0].paging.token;
    }
    return terms;
}
```

Comment: I'm getting a CORS error from this.

Comment: I got it working with axios